# Place UILabel next to UIView using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I want to place a UIView to the right of a UILabel, horizontally. The UILabel has a variable width, depending on the text in it. Graphically:

|This is text|My view|

|This is long long text|My view|

Can you point me how to create this interface programmatically using Auto Layout?

I have this:

```
self.myLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
self.myView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];

[self addSubview:self.myLabel];
[self addSubview:self.myLabel];
```

But now I need Auto Layout constraints to place `myView` to the right of `myLabel`, and make `myLabel` width fit the text it contains. Do you know how this is done?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set dynamic width for your UILabel by using *sizeToFit*

```
[self.myLabel sizeToFit]
```

After than you will get the maximum x of the frame by

```
CGRectGetMaxX(self.myLabel.frame)
```

So if you want to place the view next to the label the set the view's frame as

```
self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.myLabel.frame)+10, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

Comment: Auto Layout constraint doesnt fit your label width to your text size. you need to use the above method for that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is a label with a fixed number of lines it knows about its own width and you don‘t have to set this specifically. The constraint for laying them out horizontally would be the following.

```
NSMutableDictionary viewsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[self.myLabel, self.myView] forKeys:@[@"mylabel", @"myview"]];
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[mylabel]-[myview]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
```

This constraint only specifies the horizontal layout. To make this work you have to specify the vertical position as well so the constraint system can figure out where to position your views exactly.